# coldfusion - rounding to nearest 5 cents

Tags: coldfusion

In coldfusion, how does one round a decimal to the nearest 5 cents? So that a figure of 0.39675 would round up to 0.40. And if the figure was 0.3690, it would round down to 0.35. 
I can't seem to find anything useful via google.

Sorry for the brief question, but I think that's all I can really input.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Multiply by 20, round it, divide by 20:

```
  RoundedNumber = ( Round( Number * 20 ) / 20 )
```