# In ColdFusion, is there a numberFormat() mask to drop the decimal if it is 0?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, number-formatting

I'm trying to format numbers so that 2 decimal places show up, unless it is a whole number - then I don't want a decimal point to show.  I've tried `0.00`, `_.__`, `9.99` and several combinations.  Is there a mask for the `numberFormat` function that can get this result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<cfif int(x) eq x>
  #int(x)#
<cfelse>
  #DecimalFormat(x)#
</cfif>
```

Comment: Yuck! This should do it. reReplace(numberFormat(val, "__.00"), "\.00$", "").

Answer (score 6):

You could divide the variable by 1 and then the whole number is shown without a decimal place.

```
<cfset a = 5.00>
<cfset b = 5.55>

<cfoutput>#a/1#, #b/1#</cfoutput>
```

Output is `5, 5.55`. Instead of `5.00, 5.55` if you don't divide by 1.

Comment: That would not round to two (2) decimal places, which sounds like it is part of the requirement if I am reading it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think there is an existing function, but [this rounding example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10021060/104223) might do the trick:

```
    round(yourNumber * 100) / 100
```

**EDIT:** 
As JasonM mentioned in the comments this will not produce two decimal places for numbers like `1.1`.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment about what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: people downvote without reason all the time. It's what makes SO great! :-/ This and Henry's answer should both get the job done though.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think this answer has the same problem as mine. If `yourNumber` is `5.10` then this will output `5.1` instead of `5.10`.

Comment: @mrbusche - I think what makes it great is *collaboration*. ie Offering advice on how to improve something, or *explaining* the mistakes/pitfalls you see. That way everybody benefits. Just downvoting without explanation misses the point IMO.

Comment: @JasonM - Yep, you are right.  (Now that is what I am talking about! :)

Comment: @Leigh sorry, my sarcasm was missed on that point :) The collaboration is great, but downvoting with no explanation is just lazy and helps in no way.

Comment: @mrbusche - Gah .. I read it too quickly and missed the "tone". So I guess I am just preaching to the choir :)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I know this question is years old and my solution is dumb as hell but it worked for my needs:

```
#replace(dollarformat(list_price), '.00', '')#
```

I know this was dollarformat not number format, but the concept is the same.

LOL. If it's dumb and it works it's not dumb, right?

Answer (score 1):

Still super gross. WTF Adobe?

```
#REReplace(REReplace(DecimalFormat(value), "0+$", "", "ALL"), "\.+$", "")#
```

credit: http://www.webveteran.com/blog/web-coding/coldfusion/trimming-a-decimal-with-coldfusion-regex/

Comment: Why would you need two reReplace's? And you don't need the "ALL". Just do: #REReplace(DecimalFormat(value), "\.0+$", "")#

Comment: @Nick good question. I actually don't remember, and thank god I don't write CF anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been ages, but if you first do the Numberformat of the value, then Trim it, you will get the desired result ... NumberFormat makes it have trailing digits after the decimal - TRIM will eliminate the trailing decimals if they are just zeroes.

5.55 would result in 5.55 , 5.00 would result in 5 , 5.5 would result in 5.5

etc

Answer (score 1):

I prefer my code [as flat as a pancake](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) and try to avoid conditionals whenever possible. So if you feel comfortable dropping down a level to Java you can use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to get the results you want.

```
<cfset n = JavaCast("double", 1.0) />
<cfset x = CreateObject("java", "java.text.DecimalFormat").init() />
<cfset x.applyPattern("##.##") />
<cfset y = x.format(n) />
```

The following one liner would also work.

```
<cfset y = CreateObject("java", "java.text.DecimalFormat").init( "##.##" ).format( JavaCast("double", 1.0) ) />
```

Comment: It is because `applyPattern()` returns void. Pass the pattern string into [init](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat(java.lang.String)), call format and you should have your one-liner :)

Comment: please format your code with 4-space indentation so that the syntax is highlighted

Comment: Fixed the one liner. Thanks Leigh.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use precisionEvaluate() + numberFormat() + replaceFirst(regex)

```
<cfscript>
numberFormat( precisionEvaluate( num ), '_.00' ).replaceFirst( '\.00$', '' );
</cfscript>
```

For example:

```
50.00 -> 50
0.00 -> 0
0.001 -> 0
0.006 -> 0.01
123.45 -> 123.45
4/3 -> 1.33
5.24596 -> 5.25
pi() -> 3.14
12345678901234567890 -> 12345678901234567000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reReplace(numberFormat(val, "__.00"), "\.00$", "")
```

Comment: Please, extend your answer

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov How?